# ng-map Drawing Manager to GeoAlchemy

Tags: python, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map, geoalchemy2

I am trying to allow users on my app to define a "territory" (as a polygon).  Then others can query a point (lat and long), to determine whos territory that point falls in.  I have determined from the docs for GeoAlchemy2, that this would likely be a good tool for the job (my app is curently in dev, so I am open to other suggestions.  I am using flask, flask-sqlalchemy, and Sqlite in dev... plan on Postgres in prod.  AngularJS for frontend).

My search lead me to ng-map, specifically the drawing manager directive seen here. https://ngmap.github.io/#/!drawing-manager.html.  In modifying the example, I can get to the google onMapOverlayCompleted object.  In there I see a latLng object, but am unsure how to transform it into something I can persist in the database.  Assuming I do this in JS, can I dump it to JSON to send to my Flask API?

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?  I am more than willing to listen to better ideas.

Thanks.

Here is some code from that example:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('DrawingManagerCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function(e){
    console.log(e);
  };
});
```

How can I get the polygon from 'e'?

Comment: Please have you an idea about this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38827199/785985 on how to get the array of points. It's this code:

```
e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
```

Then you can iterate the array and get each item latitude and longitude. So your code becomes:

```
vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function(e){
  console.log(e);
  e.overlay.getPath().getArray().forEach(function (position) {
    console.log('lat', position.lat());
    console.log('lng', position.lng());
  });
}
```

Comment: Please have you an idea about this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined

Comment: @Llg Are you using my function together with GMarsh's code? You have to define `vm` variable like he did: `var vm = this;`.