# How to remove drawn polygon on Google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a map, using [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) directive, I also have a [`<drawing-manager>`](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!drawing-manager.html) which allows me to draw shapes on the map.

I just want to allow my user to draw one polygon on map, here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="CreateOrderController as vm" map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"
         map-lazy-load-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}">
        <ng-map zoom="4" center="33.134394, 53.664248"
                map-type-id="ROADMAP">
            <drawing-manager
                    on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                    drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon']}"
                    drawingControl="true"
                    drawingMode="null">
            </drawing-manager>
        </ng-map>
    </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
var vm = this;


$scope.googleMapsUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKeyIsHere&sensor=false&libraries=drawing";
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        vm.map = map;
});


vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function(e){
    var shapePath=e.overlay.getPath().getArray();  //This returns an array of drawn polygon cordinates

    //Just for example, here I want to delete the drawn polygon:
    $scope.deletePolygon();
};


$scope.deletePolygon = function() {
    //According to Google's docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove
    vm.map.setMap(null);
};
```

The `deletePolygon` function returns an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: vm.map.setMap is not a function

I know that map object does not contain `setMap` function, but [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_remove) says I can remove a polygon shape using `setMap(null)`

Any idea about how to remove/delete the polygon shape?

Comment: Please have you an idea about this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined

Comment: @Llg could you please take a look at the defined answer. Does it help you?

Comment: Thank you I have solved the problem :) Can you please take a look of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748609/draw-polygon-using-ngmap

Comment: @Llg Perfecto! Good that answer solved your problem

Comment: Please how can I display a polygon in this map. I have all the coordinates and I want to let the user delete the old polygon (edit mode) and draw the new one?

Comment: @Llg Do you use Angular ngmap or you're just using Google SDK on your website?

Comment: I'm using Angular ngmap

Comment: @Llg I will let you know, I am just on my holiday and I don't have access to the project source code, or git server right now. Please keep searching, if you could not find the answer, mention me in next two days. I will help you then.

Comment: Okay I will :) and thank you sooo much

Comment: @Llg No problem, that's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback function of the `overlaycomplete` event is passed a parameter of type `google.maps.drawing.OverlayCompleteEvent`, which according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayCompleteEvent) has `overlay` parameter, referencing to the newly created object. You need to call `.setMap(null)` on that object. So your code should look something like this:

```
vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function(e){
    var shapePath= e.overlay.getPath().getArray();  //This returns an array of drawn polygon cordinates

    e.overlay.setMap(null); //this will delete any created shape (polygon, polyline, etc) right after it is created. If you want to instead delete it later, just store the reference to overlay and call setMap(null) on it later.
};
```

Comment: I was playing with overlay, but I did not saw the function that time, and I was looking for `setMap` function in `e` object :)

Thank you, very good answer and useful

Comment: When I tried, after overlay complete, the drawing manager options to draw the shapes have gone, but no change for the already drawn shapes.

Comment: Please have you an idea about this error? `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , clearMap() will delete all your polygon , circle , line from map

```
        NgMap.getMap({id: 'mapId'}).then(function (map) {
            $scope.map = map;
        }).catch(function (map) {
            console.error('map error: ', map);
        });

        $scope.onMapOverlayCompleted = onMapOverlayCompleted;
       $scope.clearMap = clearMap;

       function onMapOverlayCompleted(e) {
            $scope.map = e;
       }

       function clearMap() {
            if ($scope.map.overlay) {
                $scope.map.overlay.setMap(null);
            }
        }
```